# AutoCompleteExtender Works Only After Postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

The AutoCompleteExtender works only after there is a postback. The first time the page loads, and user types in the textbox, it doesnt work. But after there is a postback like checkedChanged, buttonClick etc, & user types now, the suggestion list shows up. Its like... the extender is activated only after postbacks.

ASPX:

```
<asp:radiobutton id="rbenter" runat="server" text="enter code" groupname="search"
    oncheckedchanged="rbenter_change" autopostback="true"/>

<asp:radiobutton id="rbselect" runat="server" text="select code" 
 groupname="search" oncheckedchanged="rbselect_change" autopostback="true"/>

<asp:TextBox ID="txtSearch" runat="server" OnTextChanged="txtSearch_TextChanged" 
     onchange="itemSelected();"></asp:TextBox>
   <asp:AutoCompleteExtender ID="ace" runat="server" TargetControlId="txtSearch" 
     MinimumPrefixLength="2" EnableCaching="true" CompletionSetCount="10"  
     CompletionInterval="0" ServiceMethod="GetCodes" UseContextKey="True"
     CompletionListCssClass="autoComplete"
     CompletionListItemCssClass="autoCompleteItem"   
     CompletionListHighlightedItemCssClass="autoCompleteHL"
     >
    </asp:AutoCompleteExtender>
```

### EDIT:

I found out the culprit. It was the txtSearch.focus() on page_load that was causing this. On page load, the txtSearch gets focus. When I comment this, works fine. But I still wonder, how it works on postback, when it gets focus then. I wish I could make it work on page first load even when it has focus.

CS:

```
protected void Page_Load()
{
  if(!IsPostBack)
   {
     rbenter.checked=true;
     rbselect.checked=false;
     txtSearch.visible=true;
     //txtSearch.focus();  -- works fine when commented
   }
}   

protected void rbenter_change()
{
  txtSearch.visible=true;
     txtSearch.focus();
}

protected void rbselect_change()
{
  txtSearch.visible=false;

}
```

Comment: can you provide `itemSelected` function?

Comment: what do you do with itemSelected ?

Comment: The suggestion list will show like C01(Sweden). On selecting an item the textbox should only show - C01...and hence the itemSelected(). Its working fine.

Answer (score 1):

update your update panel as mentioned below :

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <Triggers>
        // Few Other triggers
        <%--<asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="txtSearch"/>--%>
    </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtSearch" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnTextChanged="txtSearch_TextChanged"
            onchange="itemSelected(this);" ></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:AutoCompleteExtender ID="AutoCompleteExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtSearch"
            MinimumPrefixLength="1" EnableCaching="true" CompletionSetCount="10"
            CompletionInterval="0" ServiceMethod="GetCodes" UseContextKey="True"
            CompletionListCssClass="autoComplete"
            CompletionListItemCssClass="autoCompleteItem"
            CompletionListHighlightedItemCssClass="autoCompleteHL">
        </asp:AutoCompleteExtender>

    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: Thank You. I see that you have commented "txtSearch" as a trigger and added 'this' to itemSelected(). I tried them. No luck. The extender still works only after there is a postback. I am baffled.

Comment: I also tried without the updatepanel/ and no triggers. Is there something like making the page know that its a postback even when its not...page.ispostback=true..:)

Comment: can you post your whole aspx page ?

Comment: Gladly... but its around 400 lines.. Any other way I could send it? Or I will try the trimmed down  version

Comment: ohhh. do one thing just remove the **onchange="itemSelected(this);"** from textbox and put the breakpoint on **GetCodes** methods and check whether break point is executed firsttime or not.

Comment: Have you checked the same scenario by creating sample application ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42114/discussion-between-spidercode-and-ruby)

Answer (score 1):

If you land to your page from a `SERVER.TRANSFER` instruction `AUTOCOMPLETE` won't run until first postback; use `RESPONSE.REDIRECT` instead of `SERVER.TRASFER` and everything will be fine.

Comment: This was the problem for me. Thanks!